# How to fix Get Data Body from Request Header Transfer-encoding:chunked in php

Tags: http, request

Currently, there is a request post with the header Transfer-encoding:chunked instead of Content-length, but the data in the body content cannot be retrieved. The server being used is Apache, tried downgrate 1.0 , but still did not solve the problem. Hope everybody help please

I had config in Apache
<Files *.php>
SetEnv downgrade-1.0